Writing pytest with JWT token in class
I have a class TestSecured and in it, I have methods that will get endpoints that are protected, so you need a jwt to make a request. I am trying to optimize my test class so that I don't need to do the login process 3 times but only 1 and use the same token in my 3 tests method.
@pytest.mark.usefixtures("client", "auth", "setup_user_and_token")
class TestSecured:
        

    def test_get_operations(self, client, setup_user_and_token):
        # headers = {'Authorization' : f'Beare {setup_user_and_token}'}
        response = client.get(f'{SECURED_ROUTE}get-operations', headers=setup_user_and_token)
        assert response.status_code == 200

    def test_post_operation(self, client, auth):
        return "ok"


    def test_post_ope2(self,client,auth):
        print("ok")


It works if I set headers in each method with the setup_user_and_token() fixture I created.
@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def setup_user_and_token(auth):
    response = auth.login()
    token = response.get_json()['access_token']
    return {'Authorization' : f'Bearer {token}'}

But I want to use the setup_class() to do this only once. How can I achieve this?
EDIT:
Below it is my conftest.py file where I defined some fixtures:
@pytest.fixture
def app():
    app = create_app({
        'TESTING' : True,
    })
    yield app
   
    with app.app_context():
        db.drop_all()


@pytest.fixture
def client(app):
    return app.test_client()


class AuthActions(object):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self._client = client

    def login(self, username='test_user', password='test_pass'):
        return self._client.post(
            '/auth/login',
            json={'username': username, 'password': password}
        )

    def logout(self):
        return self._client.get('/auth/logout')

def auth(client):
    return AuthActions(client)

@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def setup_user_and_token(auth):
    response = auth.login()
    token = response.get_json()['access_token']
    return {'Authorization' : f'Bearer {token}'}


You can add a fixture to the test class and use the fixtures there
class TestSecured:

    @pytest.fixture(scope="class", autouse=True)
    def setup_class(self, setup_user_and_token, client, auth):
        TestSecured.__setup_user_and_token = setup_user_and_token
        TestSecured.__client = client
        TestSecured.__auth = auth

    def test_get_operations(self):
        # headers = {'Authorization' : f'Beare {setup_user_and_token}'}
        response = client.get(f'{SECURED_ROUTE}get-operations', headers=self.__setup_user_and_token)
        assert response.status_code == 200

    def test_post_operation(self):
        # do something with self.__client
        # do something with self.__auth
        return "ok"

    def test_post_ope2(self):
        print("ok")

You should also remove the usefixtures marker, you use it or call the fixtures directly, see reference.

Hi I have tried the following  but it gives me the error: ScopeMismatch: You tried to access the function scoped fixture setup_user_and_token with a class scoped request object. Requesting fixture stack: tests/routes/test_secured.py:10:  def setup_class(setup_user_and_token, client, auth) Requested fixture: tests/conftest.py:57:  def setup_user_and_token(auth)

@LeoEl setup_user_and_token in your code has a function scope, but in your example it's a class scope. In any case it need to have class scope to work.

I added my conftest.py file in question because I do have the class scope but it still not work

@LeoEl auth, and any other fixture in the chain, need to have class scope. auth is also missing @pytest.fixture in your code.

@LeoEl but this is not the specific issue here, the error message say function scoped fixture setup_user_and_token. Do you have another conftest or another fixture with the same name?

Ok yes it's working many thanks

no I only have conftest files with some fixture and that's it the rest is in the class above
